# My word 365 has stopped working. Several correction attempts without result

Tags: ms-word

I have been working with office 365 for a long time on Windows 8 without problems. About fifteen years ago the Word application stopped working. I followed the following resolution tracks but without outcome:

1. Manual repair and in-line repair from the office.
2. Uninstalling printer drivers.
3. Completely uninstalling the office and reinstalling it again, twice.
4. Reaching COM complements and unchecking them one by one. Some time during the repetition of this maneuver, by a clumsy handling, I deleted the following two COM add-ins:

   ```
     a) OneNote related Notes add-ins.

     b) OneNote Notes on Word documents.
   ```

I tried to grab these add-ins to add them to their original place by reinstalling the OneNote application but during the final installation I get a message indicating that I am missing a winsqlite3.dll component on my computer.

Please help me with this problem. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Did I catch that correctly? "About fifteen ***years*** ago the Word application stopped working." Are you sure the problem is still current?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Questions on general MS Word usage are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an appropriate end-user forum (e.g., MS Answers) instead.